# query datetime string with time value

Tags: php, mysql

i have a datetime string in my DB like "2010-08-15 00:00:00" 
how do i query only the time part. suppose i want to retrieve all rows that have the time "00:20:00"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE TIME(datetimefield) = '00:00:00'`

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%H:%i:%s') = '00:20:00'
```